# SQL Injection to enumerate the columns

Tags: sql, code-injection

Following query is used to fetch all the tables from the database

```
1 = select top 1 name 
    from sys.tables 
    where object_id = (select top 1 object_id 
                       from (select top 5 object_id 
                             from sys.tables 
                             order by object_id
                            )sq 
                       order by object_id DESC 
                      )
```

How can I enumerate all the vulnerable columns from the database using a similar approach of sys.columns

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "vulnerable" columns?

Comment: What is `1 = select top 1 name . .  ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `row_number()` instead :

```
select t.name 
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by object_id) as seq
      from sys.tables t
     ) t
where seq = 5;
```